# execute Python within ConTeXt

Tags: context, python

Is there any way to execute Python code in ConTeXt document ? In LaTeX we have pythontex.

For example :

```tex
\starttext
\startpython
print("text")
\stoppython
text
\stoptext
```

Comment: Can you be more precise? If you want to execute commands passed via `python3 -c`, it's very easy to catch an output using `io.popen` in Lua (which ConTeXt uses). If you want to run files instead, the `filter` module could help.

Comment: Both will be welcome. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For comparison, here is how you would implement something similar to Jairo's solution using the [t-filter](https://github.com/adityam/filter) module.

```
\usemodule[filter]
\defineexternalfilter
  [python]
  [
    filtercommand={python \externalfilterinputfile\space > \externalfilteroutputfile},
    output={\externalfilterbasefile.tex},
    cache=yes,
    % directory=temp, if you want to redirect all temp files to a subdir
  ]
```

Yup, that's it! The option `cache=yes` caches the results, so python is rerun only if the content of the buffer or environment has changed. You can also store the output in a temp directory so that the results are out of sight. See the documentation of the filter module for other features (including proper XML export!)

The t-filter module writes everything to external files and as such might be slightly slower that the `pipe.io` method proposed by Jario.

The example given by Jairo works with a little change: `\process<filter>buffer` provided by the filter module uses square brackets instead of curly brackets. For completeness, here is the complete example:

```
\usemodule[filter]
\defineexternalfilter
  [python]
  [
    filtercommand={python \externalfilterinputfile\space > \externalfilteroutputfile},
    output={\externalfilterbasefile.tex},
    cache=yes,
    % directory=temp, if you want to redirect all temp files to a subdir
  ]


\starttext
\startimath
\startpython
import math
print(math.cos(3.141592))
\stoppython
\stopimath

\startpython
Sentence1 = "{fmt} is {adj}".format(fmt="Con\\TeX t", adj="great")
print(Sentence1)
\stoppython

%https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples
\startbuffer[hcf]
# Python program to find H.C.F of two numbers

# define a function
def compute_hcf(x, y):

# choose the smaller number
    if x > y:
        smaller = y
    else:
        smaller = x
    for i in range(1, smaller+1):
        if((x % i == 0) and (y % i == 0)):
            hcf = i 
    return hcf

num1 = 54 
num2 = 24

print("The H.C.F. is", compute_hcf(num1, num2))
\stopbuffer

\startbuffer[powersof2]
# Display the powers of 2 using anonymous function

terms = 10

# Uncomment code below to take input from the user
# terms = int(input("How many terms? "))

# use anonymous function
result = list(map(lambda x: 2 ** x, range(terms)))

print("The total terms are:",terms)
for i in range(terms):
   print("2 raised to power",i,"is",result[i])
\stopbuffer

%Adapted from
%https://www.w3schools.com/python/
\startbuffer[anotherpython]
b = "I prefer Lua over Python"
print(b[9:])
a = ("d", "e", "k", "n", "u", "t", "h")
x = slice(2)
print(a[x])
\stopbuffer
\processpythonbuffer[hcf]

\processpythonbuffer[anotherpython]

\processpythonfile{abc.py}

\startlines
\processpythonbuffer[powersof2]
\stoplines

\stoptext
```

Comment: Oh, cool :D I'd use `optional` instead of `string` to stick to the bracket syntax, but it seems it's only available in LMTX. I think I could have used `array`, but whatever. Elegant solution :)

Comment: Thank you @Aditya, your answer is elegant !

Comment: @Aditya Can we put result of python in math equation? Eg: `\startpython


from sympy import apart
from sympy.abc import x

print(apart( (x+1)/(x-1), x))
`  I need to put the result of the `print` within `$...$`

Comment: The filter module just reads the output file. So you can format the output of python as you want..

Answer (score 6):

There's a quick and dirty solution using [buffers](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Buffers_in_LuaTeX). Some remarks:

- I've defined (1) `\startpython ... \stoppython` to process Python content immediately, (2) `\processpythonbuffer` to process a buffer as a Python file with `print` functions, and (3) `\processpythonfile` to do the same as (1), but using a file instead of a buffer. (1) serves to get the result *ipso facto*, whereas the last ones are useful to delay or reuse a Python piece of code. I realized you asked for the first, so better late...
- For buffers I'm creating a temporary file named `ctxpythonbuffer.py` which is executed and then removed. Unless you have a file with such a name, you won't have any problem. I'd use `\savebuffer`, but it seems to be slower.
- Both for buffers and files I'm using `io.popen` to capture command line output. I don't know if Python has bindings to Lua or vice versa, but you could do further research. Btw if you want to go deeper, you may find Luigi Scarso's experiment, LuaTeX lunatic, interesting. Details [here](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/User:Luigi.scarso/luatex_lunatic) and [here](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-3/tb96scarso.pdf). I won't, as I don't like Python.
- `python3` is hardcoded, but you may change it to `python`, `python2` or whatever command your OS recognizes as a valid call to Python. If you want to add, say, a switch between versions or other settings, [CLD manual](https://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/cld-mkiv.pdf) is a nice starting point to write your own commands via Lua. **Bonus:** you learn another programming language, if you haven't embraced Lua yet `;)`

```python
#abc.py
#Dummy file
print("a")
print("b")
print("c")
```

```
%\setuppapersize[A6]
\startluacode

userdata = userdata or {}
local implement = interfaces.implement
local suffix = ".py"

--Adapted from:
--https://gist.github.com/dukeofgaming/453cf950abd99c3dc8fc
local pythonbuffer = 
function(file)
    local handle = assert(io.popen(string.format("python3 %s", file), 'r'))
    local output = assert(handle:read('*a'))
    handle:close()
    return output
end

userdata.processpythonbuffer =
function (content) 
    local name = "ctxpythonbuffer.py"
    io.savedata(name,content)
    result = pythonbuffer(name)
    os.remove(name)
    return result
end

userdata.processpythonfile =
function (name)
    assert(name ~= "", "File name needed")
    name = name:find(suffix.."$") and name or name..suffix
    return pythonbuffer(name)
end

implement{
    name        = "processpythonbuffer",
    public      = true,
    arguments   = {"string"},
    actions     = function(s)
        context(userdata.processpythonbuffer(buffers.getcontent(s)))
    end
}

implement{
    name        = "processpythonfile",
    public      = true,
    arguments = {"string"},
    actions     = function(s)
        context(userdata.processpythonfile(s))
    end
}

\stopluacode
%Buffer name isn't really important
%You could use another, less verbose...
\def\startpython%
    {\def\stoppython{\processpythonbuffer{ctx_python_buffer}}%
    \dostartbuffer[ctx_python_buffer][startpython][stoppython]}
\starttext
\startimath
\startpython
import math
print(math.cos(3.141592))
\stoppython
\stopimath

\startpython
Sentence1 = "{fmt} is {adj}".format(fmt="Con\\TeX t", adj="great")
print(Sentence1)
\stoppython

%https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples
\startbuffer[hcf]
# Python program to find H.C.F of two numbers

# define a function
def compute_hcf(x, y):

# choose the smaller number
    if x > y:
        smaller = y
    else:
        smaller = x
    for i in range(1, smaller+1):
        if((x % i == 0) and (y % i == 0)):
            hcf = i 
    return hcf

num1 = 54 
num2 = 24

print("The H.C.F. is", compute_hcf(num1, num2))
\stopbuffer

\startbuffer[powersof2]
# Display the powers of 2 using anonymous function

terms = 10

# Uncomment code below to take input from the user
# terms = int(input("How many terms? "))

# use anonymous function
result = list(map(lambda x: 2 ** x, range(terms)))

print("The total terms are:",terms)
for i in range(terms):
   print("2 raised to power",i,"is",result[i])
\stopbuffer

%Adapted from
%https://www.w3schools.com/python/
\startbuffer[anotherpython]
b = "I prefer Lua over Python"
print(b[9:])
a = ("d", "e", "k", "n", "u", "t", "h")
x = slice(2)
print(a[x])
\stopbuffer
\processpythonbuffer{hcf}

\processpythonbuffer{anotherpython}

\processpythonfile{abc}

%\startlines ... \stoplines is the rough equivalent of Plain/LaTeX \obeylines
\startlines
\processpythonbuffer{powersof2}
\stoplines

\stoptext
```

[image]